# Caching a python virtualenv for CI

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

As part of my CI I create a python `virtualenv (venv)` and then execute the tests within.

The problem is that just installing what is needed takes about 1 minute (which is quite long in comparison to the tests).

I'm wondering if I can cache the `venv`, and yet being able to automatically get a clean environment, installed by the updated `requirements.txt` file from the repository

Comment: Several CI servers document a way to cache specific directories.  Without editing your question to include what CI server you're running your pipeline in, attempted answer will go in different directions.